# Laravel 5.1 ERROR Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\sendRegistermail()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, mandrill

I am trying to send automated mails via Mandrill in my Laravel 5.1 project. It was working but I was setting up my Mandrill Calls in my AuthController now I wanna have a class App\Marketing where all my functions for sending email will be stored. So in my controllers after an actions happens I can just call up the function with 1 line of code, but this line is giving me troubles I think.

my App\Marketing class looks like this now

```
class Marketing{

private $mandrill;

/**
* Via construct injection
*
*/
public function __construct(Mail $mandrill)
{
    $this->mandrill = $mandrill;
}

public function sendRegistermail()
{
    // In template content you write your dynamic content if you use <mc:edit> tags.
    $template_content = [];
    $message = array(
        'subject' => 'Welkom bij SP*RK! - Jouw accountgegevens',
        'from_email' => 'noreply@spark.com',
        'from_name' => 'SP*RK',
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'name' => $request->input('name'),
                'type' => 'to'
            )
        ),
        'merge_vars' => array(
            array(
                'rcpt' => $request->input('email'),
                'vars' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NAME',
                        'content' => $request->input('name')
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'EMAIL',
                        'content' => $request->input('email')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    //email validation
    if (str_contains($request['email'], "@kuleuven.be")) {
        MandrillMail::messages()->sendTemplate('registration-mail', $template_content, $message);
    } else {
        MandrillMail::messages()->sendTemplate('registration-mail-notactive', $template_content, $message);
    }
}

// ----- OR  -------    

/**
* Via method injection
*
*/
public function sendMail(Mail $mandrill, $data)
{
    $mandrill->messages()->sendTemplate($data)
}

// ----- OR  -------

/**
* Via the Facade
*
*/
public function sendMailByFacade($data)
{
    \MandrillMail::messages()->sendTemplate($data);
}
}
```

This is how I try to call the function after registration in my postRegister function:

```
sendRegistermail();

return redirect($this->redirectPath());
```

Comment: `sendRegistermail` is a method of your `Marketing` class, you should call it on an instance of that object

Comment: Could you help me on how to do this? I am kinda new to Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

`sendRegistermail` is a method of your `Marketing` class, you should call it on an instance of that object

So, first of all you have to create a `Marketing` object instance in your controller. A good way to do this it's by injecting the dependency in the constructor, like this:

```
//your controller class
class Controller
{
    protected $marketing;

    //Your controller's constructor
    public function __construct(Marketing $marketing)
    {
        $this->marketing = $marketing;
    }
}
```

Or you can use one of the other methods you have provided in your code to inject the instance.

Once you have an instance of the `Marketing` class, you only need to call the `sendRegistermail` method on that instance. In your controller method:

```
//call the method on the marketing instance
$this->marketing->sendRegistermail();
```

Comment: I've tried your method and I get this error Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::$marketing on this line $this->marketing->sendRegistermail(); in my controller

Comment: you should verify that when the controller is built, the `marketing` instance is injected correcty, check in the constructor with a `dd($marketing)` to check it's value

Comment: I've tried something like this:  $Marketing = new Marketing;
        $Marketing->sendRegistermail() and I think it works because now I get errors in my Marketing.php file

Comment: I get this error Undefined variable: request on this line 'email' => $request->input('email'), I guess my class can't read the input fields of my form any idea how my class can reach the input fields

Comment: your `$request` variable isn't accessible from inside your class, so you have to pass the data from your controller to your class. For example you could pass it as a parameter of the method: `$Marketing->sendRegistermail($request)`

Comment: How do I access the data in my class?

Comment: from your method you can access the data as a parameter

Comment: You can access the request anywhere with `request()->input('email')`, but as @Moppo very well suggested, you should pass the needed data as method parameters. So your method definition should look like this `public function sendRegistermail($name, $email)`, and call it like this from your controller, `$this->marketing->sendRegistermail($request->input('name'), $request->input('email'));`.